# read one value from read_csv error

Tags: python-3.x

```
tst = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Desktop/stuff/Et2Load.csv', header=0,delimiter="\t", quoting=3)
    print(tst.head(2))  # ok
    #print(tst['date'][0])
```

I made up this file, one line header 2 lines 
3 columns, 2 lines
                               id,date,coldata

0  1,August 18 2016,"With all this stuff going do...

1  2,August 19 2016,this is a great movie. The mu...

i cannot access a specific "cell"
print(tst['date'][0]) error

return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'date'

Comment: I can see a difference between the reading of the column and mine. I try the kaggle, >>> train.columns.values
array([id, sentiment, review], dtype=object) i get ['id,date,coldata'] on my data. they have an array i have something else. crap. https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words

Comment: ok i will build the file from python and not from excel i might get lucky

Answer (score 0):

well this is the big secret:

```
set_index('name the column that going to be used as 'id'')
```

It was difficult to find this one.